# Multiples láminas en una sola lámina - presentación beamer

Tags: latex

Mi consulta es la siguiente, tengo una presentación en beamer, pero ahora debo hacer que en una sola plana esté 4 o 6 de las láminas, algo como lo de la foto
[image: multiples láminas]

Alguien sabe como hacerlo? sería de gran ayuda. Saludos a todos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías utilizar el paquete `pgfpages`de la siguiente manera:

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
  \usepackage{pgfpages}
\mode<handout>{\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black!20}}
\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[letterpaper,border shrink=5mm]
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Frame A
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
Frame B
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
Frame C
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
Frame D
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Como habrás observado, la magia viene de la configuración:

```
\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}
```

Te acepta 2, 4, 8 y 16 por página.

La pripedad `border shrink` te permite controlar el espacio entre diapositivas.